# C# RSA decrypt parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, encryption, rsa

I am trying to decrypt communication from web sockets secured with SSL certificate. The certificate is installed on the machine and the private key is present. I have this decrypt function

```
public static string DecryptTry(X509Certificate2 x509, string stringTodecrypt)
{
        try
        {
            if (x509 == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTodecrypt))
                throw new Exception("A x509 certificate and string for decryption must be provided");

            if (!x509.HasPrivateKey)
                throw new Exception("x509 certificate does not contain a private key for decryption");

            if(x509 == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("certificate is null");
                return "";
            }

            Console.WriteLine("decoding text with private key " + x509.HasPrivateKey);//true

            using (RSA csp = (RSA)x509.PrivateKey)
            {
                byte[] bytestoDecrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringTodecrypt).Take(256).ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("key size: " + x509.PrivateKey.KeySize + " received data length: " + stringTodecrypt.Length + " bytes length: " + bytestoDecrypt.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytestoDecrypt));
                byte[] bytesDecrypted = csp.Decrypt(bytestoDecrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256); //ERROR HERE

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error while decrypting text: " + e.Message + e.HResult +  e.StackTrace);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

But the `csp.Decrypt` is throwing an error

> parameter is incorrect

I have tried all padding parameters - none of the seemed to make a difference.
Does anybody know where the problem might be? Am I missing something?
**

### EDIT 25.12.2020

**
To add some more background info: The website where the WebSocket client is listening is secured HTTPS, the SSL certificate is signed by CA with my full access to all of its information. The initial problem is handshake for the WebSocket communication which comes encrypted. I was thinking I would be able to decrypt it with the private key and that is where the problem occurs. The length of the incoming request (or handshake) is between 490 and 520 bytes, so that is the reason for `.Take(256)`. I was thinking to split the text into multiple, decode them separately and put together after. That, however, brought me here.
One final thought: This is a .NET console application. Could the problem be possibly fixed by converting it to a format that IIS accepts? The IIS on the machine has the certificate installed... could it possibly make a difference?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringTodecrypt).Take(256)` explain why you chose UTF8 and why you are taking 256 characters.

Comment: Can you post the encryption code? If the ciphertext has really been decoded with UTF8, it has generally been corrupted by this. If a ciphertext should be converted to a string, then a suitable binary-to-text encoding such as Base64 must be used. Note: (1) For RSA the lengths of the ciphertext (e.g. 256 byte) and key (e.g. 2048 bit) are identical. (2) The length of the plaintext must not exceed the length of the key minus the length required by the padding. (3) Other possible bugs are: A non-matching padding or a corrupted ciphertext (e.g. an incomplete one with respect to `Take(256)`).

Comment: Also, if your communication is using websockets over TLS then the websocket stack has already taken care of encryption and decryption for you.

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for my late response. Thank you for your comments, they made it a little bit more clear to me. I have edited the post to add more background information about my intentions and clarify some of my steps. a thing worth mentioning is that I do not encrypt the text, the text already comes encrypted since the webpage is using SSL certificate. That is at least what I think, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: One last thing to add: I managed to make it working with converting the result in Encryption function to base64string and decoding it in decryption. The problem is though, that I do not control the encryption. So maybe I should change my question to: "what encoding is used for HTTPS communication and how do get its encrypted data?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve:

- Decrypt something using RSA
- Decrypt TLS layer of HTTP
- Decrypt something in Websocket protocol

I think that you should give some more informations how it works. Can you show example input for function function, means:

`DecryptTry(X509Certificate2 x509, string stringTodecrypt) { ... }`

How 'strindTodecypt' looks like? What do you put there?
How do you connect to this server to get data to decrypt, via TLS?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. The function is intended to decrypt data coming though the websocket from client to the server. The client's website is secured with HTTPS with a certificate signed by CA I got full access to. The websocket connection fails since I cannot handshake the client without decrypting the data.