# Cross-server SSL certificate for Websockets

Tags: ssl, encryption, websocket

I was studying Websockets (wss) and I am a little confused about their use of SSL. I hope some of you will be able to clarify some things that cause the most confusion to me.

---

### Use scenario

Let's say I have an HTTPS secured website with a certificate signed by CA. I would like to communicate with a custom app in real-time (using the WebSockets) running on an external server that is not using the same domain (the site is for example [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and the server is [www.notmysite.com](http://www.notmysite.com)).

### The confusion part

1. When the WebSocket client (wss) is connecting to the remote server, what SSL certificate does it use? Is it of the origin website, or of the server it is trying to connect to?
2. Given the scenario, can a connection be established with a single-domain SSL certificate - only for the website ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)) where we know the private key and therefore we should be able to decrypt the encrypted data?
3. If question no. 2 is false, would multi-domain certificate containing both urls fix the problem?

---

### The background story

I was trying to make a WebSocket server in .NET C#. I managed to get it working with HTTP however when I tried the code on HTTPS secured website I was presented with an encrypted text I could not really work with. That is why I bought an SSL certificate and put it on the website thinking that if I have the private key I can decrypt the data and communicate with the client (basically question no.2). Though I was only presented with different errors regarding cryptography. I was trying to figure this out for over a week and my progress and frustration can be seen in my other questions such as:
[C# RSA decrypt parameter is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432353/c-sharp-rsa-decrypt-parameter-is-incorrect) and
[AuthenticateAsServer() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457778/authenticateasserver-an-unknown-error-occurred-while-processing-the-certificat)
Then I figured out I may need to look at it from a different point and that's when I came up with this theory. I hope some of you will be able to end my suffering with an explanation of why what I did was wrong. I appreciate any help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if the multi-domain SSL certificate solved this issue since I combined it with using a premade library (WebsocketsSharp) which along with the new multi-domain certificate works perfectly. In my opinion, the multi-domain certificate is needed if you want to communicate between two different servers (either website and server or two servers).
I hope I will save some future headaches.